# determining the size of the buffer at run time? (socket programming)

Tags: c++, c, sockets

In order to determine the type of message received in a UDP packet, there is a need to look at specific buffer element [i] received from "recvfrom" in order to discern the type of message intended. first, i use  a buffer in the stack to populate the buffer (of recvfrom), i know the maximum size of the message i should receive.

So say my array buffer is of 300 bytes, and i receive a packets of different sizes (e.g. 30, 80, 210 byes etc)....how can i know the size received (this is because there are few other criteria i test for to determine the nature of the message )

Knowing the size will enable me to use memcpy to an object.

i'm thinking of strlen(udp packet) because it is determined at runtime as opposed to compile time.
the problem is what if the rest of packet was filled with junk....

I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

`recv(2)`, which is used to receive a UDP packet, returns the number of bytes received.

Comment: yep, you are right, it forgot about it the return bytes, recvfrom also returns the number of bytes. thanks a lot

Comment: you might also use memset() to set the whole buffer to ;\0' before each call to recvfrom()  And the max number of bytes to receive is part of the recvfrom() so the buffer is not overrun.

Comment: note: a UDP packet only allows a single read, so the buffer size must be >= to the max udp packet size.  Preferably greater by at least 1 byte.  The UDP packet might contain null bytes (0x00) so using the string functions would be unreliable/error prone

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i didn't resolve my problem yet, the issue resides in sizeof(pack_buff). if for example you declare char* pack_buff[100]. when i print its size it give me 800. Others said that you can't determine the size of the array the pointer points to. so even if i use mem like this memset((char*)&pack_buff,0,sizeof(pack_buff)) , i'd still need to know how to determine the size of puck_buff. I was expecting it to print simply 100 bytes (char = 1 byte).

Comment: why does sizeof(pack_buff) gives 800 if it's declared as : char* pack_buff[100];

Comment: You have `char* pack_buff[100]` (100 pointers) but you want `char pack_buff[100]` (100 bytes). `char buf[100]; sizeof(buf)` will work (but `char* buf; sizeof(buf)` won't). 
 
Setting the buffer to NULs is a waste of time. If you're going to treat the buffer as a string, you just need to add one NUL. `bytes_recvd = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0); if (bytes_recvdbuf >= 0) buf[bytes_recvd] = '\0';`.